# Searching after indexing in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, indexing

I want to index 1 billion records. each record has 2 attributes (attribute1 and attribute2).
each record that has same value in attribute1 must be merge. for example, I have two record

```
attribute1  attribute2
1   4
1   6
```

my elastic document must be

```
{
   "attribute1": "1"
   "attribute2": "4,6"
}
```

due to huge amount of data, I must to read a bulk (about 1000 records) and merge them based on the above rule (in memory) and then search them in ElasticSearch and merge them with search result and then index/reindex them.
In summary I have to Search and Index per bulk respectively. 
I implemented this rule but in some cases Elastic does not return all results and some documents have been indexed duplicately. 
after each Index I Refresh ElasticSearch so that it be ready for next search. but in some case it doesn’t work.
my index setting is followed as:

```
{
"test_index": {
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "-1",
            "translog": {
                "flush_threshold_size": "1g"
            },
            "max_result_window": "1000000",
            "creation_date": "1464577964635",
            "store": {
                "throttle": {
                    "type": "merge"
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "TZOse2tLRqGk-vHRMGc2GQ",
        "version": {
            "created": "2030199"
        },
        "warmer": {
            "enabled": "false"
        },
        "indices": {
            "memory": {
                "index_buffer_size": "40%"
            }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "merge": {
           "policy": {
                "max_merge_size": "2g"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I resolve this problem?

Is there any other setting to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bulk commands, you need to use the `index` operation for the first occurence and then `update` with a script to update your `attribute2` property:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_type" : "test_type", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "attribute1" : "1", "attribute2": [4] }
{ "update" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_type" : "test_type", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "script" : { "inline": "ctx._source.attribute2 += attr2", "params" : {"attr2" : 6}}}
```

After the first `index` operation your document will look like

```
{
   "attribute1": "1"
   "attribute2": [4]
}
```

After the second `update` operation, your document will look like

```
{
   "attribute1": "1"
   "attribute2": [4, 6]
}
```

Note that it is also possible to only use `update` operations with `doc_as_upsert` and `script`.

Comment: my question is why sometimes when I index data and refresh elastic, and search on it immediately, elastic don't return result?

Comment: How do you refresh your index? I see your `refresh_interval` setting is -1, which means "never refresh".

Comment: after bulk indexing. i call refresh with API.

Comment: Are you certain that your search returns all document and you're not hitting the max `size`? Please describe how you're making your search?

Comment: I send Count request with query and get count of result, then send Search request with same query and size of previous count result to get all documents.

Comment: How much is "count" approximately? If you're using ES2, are you aware that you won't be able to get more that 10000 by default (unless you change your settings)?

Comment: And do you ever get 1000000 results? Note that you should probably use scan/scroll instead as using a window that big you're putting your ES cluster under unnecessary strain.

Comment: In Fact, I search 100 Items in a bool query 10 times simultaneously. are you sure after refreshing all documents is ready for search?

Comment: Yes, they should be there. There must be something wrong with the way you query. But again, if you use the solution I suggested, you don't need to do all the querying/merging yourself, let ES do it for you.

Comment: your solution is not practical for me because I don't know what records must be merged. in your script you know record 1 and 2 must be merge. first you index record 1 and then update with record 2.

Comment: How about using `attribute1` as the ID of the document?

Comment: in my case data indexing is dynamic, it means that on time attribute1 is key and marge is done based on it. other time key column change.

Comment: Yes, but since you're grouping on `attribute1` why not using it as the ID?